# Multiplication of the values of similar indices for a vector<Model>

Tags: c++, math, vector, computer-science

I have defined a `struct` to get a vector of index and value as the following:

```
struct Model
{
    Model(){ }
    Model(size_t i, double v): index(i), value(v){ }
    size_t index;
    double value;
};
```

then I defined a `vector<Model>` **x1** , and another one `vector<Model>` **x2**

My question:
**what is the most efficient way to multiple the values of similar indexes of those v1 and v2?**

Comment: I edit your question. You can also edit it again if you think it is not much better.

Comment: Have you tried any **operator overloading**?

Comment: Are your vectors sorted by `Model::index`?

Comment: @ François Andrieux  no, the vector might be as the following v1((1,3),(15,3),(10,2)), and v2{(1,4),(5,2)}, so the indices in v1 for example are 1,15,10 and the corresponding values are 3,3,2

Comment: @ k-five thnx for editing... i just tried to do a normal comparison between indices and it took time

Comment: Efficient in terms of time or in terms of space?

Comment: @jotik --> time